# How to take screenshot(using selection) in awesome wm via scrot

Tags: linux, bash, awesome-wm, lua

Tried:

```
awful.util.spawn("scrot -s")
awful.util.spawn("urxvt -e \"scrot -s\"")
os.execute("scrot -s")
```

and all possible combinations even with `sleep`.
Also tried daemonize.
Nothing works =(
P.S. All commands are in key bindings, if I replace `scrot -s` with `scrot`, all works, except selecting area.

Comment: This solution based on XFCE4-screenshooter: https://sergei.gnezdovi.com/category/linux/30-awesomewm/   It shows how to take window, full screen and selection area screenshot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have arguments in command line awful.util.spawn_with_shell() should be used. This

```
awful.util.spawn_with_shell("sleep 0.5 && scrot -s")
```

works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with this too. 
spawn_with_shell is not the solution that makes it work for me.
The screen flickers when I press the according hotkey, so that's configured correctly and when I press Win+r (run) and type path/to/screenshot.sh, that also works.
This is the script following the shebang

```
scrot -s '%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h_scrot.png' -e 'mv $f /home/sam/Pictures/Screenshots'
```

This are the things I've tried:

```
screenshot = "/home/sam/run/screenshot.sh"
awful.spawn.with_shell(screenshot)
```

What does work is executing the bash scripts with the terminal:
These are my variable definitions at the top of the page

```
screenshot = "/home/sam/run/screenshot.sh"
screenshot_cmd = terminal .. " -e " .. screenshot
```

And then way more down the file, I have these (both working)

```
awful.key({ modkey  ,         }, "#107", function () awful.spawn.with_shell(screenshot_cmd) end,
          {description = "take screenshot", group = "launcher"}),
awful.key({ modkey  , "Shift" }, "p", function () awful.spawn(screenshot_cmd) end,
          {description = "take screenshot", group = "launcher"}),
```

Unfortunately, the latter also opens a terminal window, which is not a desirabe behaviour
(But at least, something is working